# MySQL InnoDB - Confused about transactions

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, innodb

I've been using MySQL for many years but don't have a lot of experience using the InnoDB engine.

I'm running some tests on it now as I'm going to be using it & from what I've read it's not supposed to allow anything to "go through" if there are any problems with any of the queries in THAT transaction.

My question is then why, in the below code.... does it still input the first two queries into the database when there is clearly a problem with the third query?

```
$query = "BEGIN";
mysql_query($query);

$query = "INSERT INTO list_columns(lid,column_name) VALUES(8,'test')";
mysql_query($query);

$query = "INSERT INTO list_columns(lid,column_name) VALUES(8,'test')";
mysql_query($query);

$query = "INSERT INT list_columns(lid,column_name) VALUES(8,'test')";
mysql_query($query);

$query = "COMMIT";
mysql_query($query);
```

**Edit:** I understand about using ROLLBACK & all..... but I thought the whole purpose of transactions was so that if there was any problems at all with any of the queries in the transaction then NONE of them would be executed... or this only the case with multiple inserts in the one query for example.... if one of the inserts presents a problem, then none will be inserted?

Comment: You need to ROLLBACK if you want the other two queries removed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add to what Konerak said... this is a simplified process with [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of `mysql` for example:

```
$pdo = new PDO($mysqldsn, $user, $pass);
$pdo->beginTransaction();

try {

  $pdo->query("INSERT INTO list_columns(lid,column_name) VALUES(8,'test')");
  $pdo->query("INSERT INTO list_columns(lid,column_name) VALUES(8,'test')");
  $pdo->query("INSERT INT list_columns(lid,column_name) VALUES(8,'test')");
  $pdo->commit();

} catch (PDOException $e) {

  $pdo->rollBack();
  throw $e;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If the problem is something like "*This insert violated a unique key*", the commit will take place. You have to check yourself if the query returned errors, and if so, `ROLLBACK`.

If the problem is for example an unexpected shutdown of the server, queries 1 and 2 won't take place.

Offcourse, since your 3 queries here are the same, this is a silly example. Atleast change the `lid` to see. Why don't you do a quick test?

#### Edit: you edited your question about the purpose of transactions.

The purpose of transactions is indeed **to keep the database in a consistent state** (read up on [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)), but it is up to the programmer to decide what is consistent. Look at [prodigitalson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4819056/327563) to see an example of a possible php-way of error catching that does this for you. But while you are in a transaction, other processes will not see the changes your transaction is doing - hence atomic and isolated.

```
CREATE TABLE `testkeys` (
  `lid` INT,
  `column_name` VARCHAR(50),
  UNIQUE KEY `testuniq` (`lid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

BEGIN;
INSERT INTO testkeys(lid,column_name) VALUES(1,'test 1');
INSERT INTO testkeys(lid,column_name) VALUES(2,'test 2');
INSERT INTO testkeys(lid,column_name) VALUES(3,'test 3');
INSERT INTO testkeys(lid,column_name) VALUES(2,'test 2b');
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check it manually and if there is any error you need to rollback it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As you are executing sql query through php, it is not going to work like as in single mysql command.
In order to make above transaction to work you need wrap your code with in try catch block and set mysql_autocommit off, run insert query and use mysql_commit to commit your successful job or use mysql_rollback in catch block in case you have any error.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
try{
  mysqli_autocommit($con,FALSE);

  $query = "INSERT INTO list_columns(lid,column_name) VALUES(8,'test')";
  mysql_query($query);

  $query = "INSERT INTO list_columns(lid,column_name) VALUES(8,'test')";
  mysql_query($query);

  $query = "INSERT INT list_columns(lid,column_name) VALUES(8,'test')";
  mysql_query($query);

  mysql_commit($con);

}catch{

  mysql_rollback($con);

}
```